# Oracle SQL query to extract data for a maximum date for rows contianing the same ID

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table, say Table1:

[image]

And,  I am trying to extract data with the following conditions:

1. select all entries in column A which are 2 and 5,
2. All entries in column B which are 100
3. All data which have the contract ID 15 in column C
4. All dates, in Column D which are less than 31.02.2016, for example
5. Finally, the row(s), which has (have) the maximum value in Column G

If I use the following code (except finding the maximum date in column G), it works fine:

```
Select * from Table1
where
A in (2 , 5)
and B = 100
and C = '15'
and D <= TO_DATE ('31.01.16', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

and gives me the following result:
[image]

Now, I want to find all those rows, which have the maximum date value in column G. If I use the following to find the row in this case corresponding to maximum date in G, the query runs and I get an empty table with just the column names:

```
Select * from Table1 t1
where
A in (2 , 5)
and B = 100
and C = '15'
and D <= TO_DATE ('31.01.16', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
and G = (select MAX(G) from Table1 where G = t1.G)
```

The desired output is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can u paste your sample data rather than the image

Comment: Ray,please check the answer

Comment: @Atif: I tried and I learned that I cannot load/paste the file here. I found this link supporting it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314547/how-do-i-paste-an-excel-sheet-to-the-questions-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `FETCH`:

```
select *
from Table1
where A in (2 ,5) and
      B = 100 and
      C = '15' and
      D <= date '2016-01-31'
order by g desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that I also simplified the syntax for the date constant.

If you want *all* rows in the event of ties, then use:

```
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want one row, you can order by and limit:

```
Select * 
from Table1
where
    A in (2 , 5)
    and B = 100
    and C = 15
    and D <= date '2016-01-31'
order by d desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

If you want to allow top ties, then you can use `fetch first 1 row with ties` instead.

Notes

- I used a literal date rather than `to_date()`: this is simpler to write and more efficient (note that your original format specification was wrong, as the string has no time portion)
- it looks like column `C` is numeric, so I removed the single quotes around the literal value in the condition  (you can change it back if the column is of a string datatype)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the notes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get  to find all those rows, which have the maximum date value in column Get, then you can use window function dense_rank().  Rows with the same values for the rank criteria will receive the same rank values:

```
--get all rows with num=1
Select * from
(
Select *, dense_rank() over (order by G desc) num
where
A in (2 , 5)
and B = 100
and C = '15'
and D <= TO_DATE ('31.01.16', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
) X
Where num=1
```